# Controle com HtmlControl ou HtmlGenericControl dentro de GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma tag html dentro de um gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...etc..etc
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg cinza" runat="server" id="icon_Nuvem"></i>
...
```

Quando a gridview esta sendo populada eu tenho o evento:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
```

Preciso trocar esse icon_nuvem que tem a class `cinza` para `laranja`

Normalmente quando utilizo por exemplo uma imagem:

```
 <asp:Image ID="img_Historico"
```

eu faria assim:

```
 Image IM_Hist = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("img_Historico");
```

Mas e no caso de um `<i>` ?
E ainda mais preciso de algo como um .`toggleClass` que troque o cinza por laranja

Não sei nem como começar;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri com a minha própria pergunta.

```
 HtmlGenericControl icon = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("icon_Nuvem");
```

Depois faço a verifição que eu quero e adiciono o style em si e não chamo um class já existente.

```
if (dr[14].ToString() == "")
{
     icon.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#808080"); //cinza
}
else
{
    icon.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "#ff6a00"); //laranja
}
```